# Full Singular Value Decomposition in R

Tags: r, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

In most applications (esp. statistical ones) the [thin SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Thin_SVD) suffices. However, on occasion one needs the full SVD in order to obtain an orthobasis of the null space of a matrix (and its conjugate). It seems that svd() in R only returns the thin version. Is it possible to produce the full version? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(sos)
> findFn("svd NULL space")
found 47 matches;  retrieving 3 pages
```

This looks on point:

[MSBVAR  null.space     Find the null space of a matrix](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/MSBVAR/html/null.space.html)

[As does this function in MASS](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/MASS/html/Null.html).

Answer (score 2):

R Core uses the routines from Linpack, Lapack, ... that it needs.

If you need something different, you probably need to either get yourself other Linpack etc routines, or connect to a library providing more.

Doug Bates just wrapped the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) library in the [RcppEigen](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppEigen) package which may have something for you. [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) appear to be both powerful and fairly featureful while being highly optimised.

Comment: Interesting. I see eigen doesn't depend on LAPACK. I wonder if it's competitive in performance or if its strenghts lie elsewhere.

Comment: It tends to be faster, with a cost of huge object files. Blog post on RcppEigen forthcoming,